# BQ2002F TS pin resistor value

Tags: voltage, resistors

How do I find the value of VT and RT such that TS will be VCC/2 at 40 deg Celsius?
[image]

Datasheet [link](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2002f.pdf).

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more on VT, what you mean by VT. RT is resistor between VCC and TS. I have worked with this chip before. may be I can help you.

Comment: VT is the voltage between the RT resistor

Comment: Check the evaluation board http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sluu007b/sluu007b.pdf pg #3. And look into the state diagram on pg# 3 of the BQ20023C. You need to set Vts to VTS < VCC/2 for trickle charge and VTS > VCC/2 for fast charge.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the resistance of the NTC at 40 degrees C. In your specific case, you want Rt to be equal to this number.

More generally, you can use the voltage divider equation:

Vts = VCC * Rntc / (Rntc + RT). Re-arrange the equation to solve for variable of interest. To be thorough, you should double check that the current flowing into the BQ2002C at Ts is negligible.